# Can the JIRA SOAP api be used to determine whether a given user can view a given record?

Tags: python, api, soap, jira

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
if jira.user_has_permission('jsmith', 'JIRA-123'):
    print '%s has permission to view %s' % (user, record)
else:
    print '%s does not have permission to view %s' % (user, record)
```

How can I implement jira.user_has_permission()?

Note: I'm looking for the ability to determine whether a user other than the user who is accessing the API has permission to view a given record.

Edit:
I'm also open a solution that tells me whether the user has permission to view records inside of a given project.  I tried using getProjectByKey, followed by getProjectWithSchemesById, but was not able to obtain the user information that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's long-winded with the standard API but here you go.

getProjectWithSchemesById gives you a RemoteProject object. Probably has to be invoked by a user with jira-admin permissions. Note that getProjectByKey does not set the permission scheme in the value returned but is a handy way to get the project id to use in getProjectWithSchemesById.

The RemoteProject object from getProjectWithSchemesById has a getPermissionScheme method that returns a RemotePermissionScheme object.

The RemotePermissionScheme object has a getRemoteEntries method

The resulting array of RemoteEntries is what you need to iterate over to look for the Browse permission and which users and groups have it.

~Matt

Comment: I think I'd probably write a custom SOAP method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The soap operation getIssue will throw a RemotePermissionException 
http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/exception/RemotePermissionException.html
when a user is trying to access a permission she shouldn't access.

Not sure how this is done in python, but I'm sure there should be a way to catch the exception in your method.

Francis

Comment: Hi Francis, I'm looking for an API to determine is a different user has permission to view the issue, not whether the user who is accessing the API has permission to view the issue.